# nested html list from json,csv

Tags: javascript, html, json, csv

I have a flat csv file like

```
name,roll,section,hh
a,1,k,34
a,1,r,5
```

you can see there is repeated data like "a" in "name". I wan to convert these as a html nested list like shown below

```
|a
---------------------
   |1
   ------------------
      |k
      ---------------
            |  34
      ---------------
      |  r
      ---------------
            |  5
            ---------
```

So i thought I can convert them to a nested json structure then in html using js.

how do I convert this data to a nested json , like below ?

```
{
"name":"a"
"roll":"1"
"section":["k","r"],
"hh":["34","5"]
}
```

}

Is there any other way to present those csv data to a html nested list ?
please help .

edit:
For the json part,I have converted csv with $.toJSON($.csv.toObjects(data))
using js plugin. but couldn't found any way to make nested json like i have shown.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given input in this CSV format:

```
name,roll,section,hh
a,1,k,34
a,1,r,5
```

Each line of the data represents a complete route from *root* to the *leaf node*. So we can split by line and accumulate it to the JSON object. Given you have a function which parses the CSV text as above to an array of tokens like this:

```
var lines = $.csv.toArrays(csv);
```

`lines` will now become a 2D array of string as follows:

```
[
    ['name','roll','section','hh'],
    ['a','1','k','34'],
    ['a','1','r','5']
]
```

Ignore the first line which is the header, iterate through each line, and accumulate the JSON object:

```
var people = [];
lines.slice(1).forEach(function(person){
    // Check if this person has already been added to the people list?
    if (people.filter().length>0){
        // Update the existing person in the list
        for (var p in people){
            if (people[p].name === person[0]){
                people[p].section.push(person[2]);
                people[p].section.push(person[3]);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        // Add a new one
        people.push({
            name: person[0],
            roll: person[1],
            section: [person[2],
            hh: [person[3]]
        });
    }
});
```